# How to burn a 7.5GB to a normal DVD-R

Tags: 11.10, burning

I'm trying to backup my God Of War PS2 game however the ISO that I created is 7.5GB large. Normal DVD-Rs however have a 4.7GB size limit. How and with which tools can I backup a DVD dual layer on a normal DVD-R?

Comment: You go an buy a Dual Layer DVD and copy the game in that disc.

Comment: You should also know that your backup will not be playable in any un-modded PS2s. So the only thing that backup would be useful for would be the PCSX2 emulator or modded systems. So if giving this game to a friend of yours was on your agenda then you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I have a modded PS2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DVD95](http://dvd95.sourceforge.net/)

It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center. It has a GUI interface. It will convert dual-layer DVD images into single-layer DVD images. These split-images are compatible with many media players as well (for movies etc.). Check their website for more details.

The application is available in English, even though following image is not.

[image: DVD95 features]

Comment: This program does not magically give you more space. It re-encodes *movies* to lower qualities so that you can fit them on smaller mediums.

Answer (score 5):

If it is just for making a backup you can use the [`split`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/split.1.html) command to split the file into 2 or more parts. Burn the parts to several 4.7 Gb discs. You can use [`cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/cat.1.html) to restore the parts to 1 file.

Another method would be to unpack the ISO and burn the files to several disc.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to be able to back up that game on a single layer disc. You simply need the storage. It's not like a DVD where you can just re-encode it to a lower quality, that game is a collection of thousands of files that need to be intact. You will need a Dual-layer disc.

If you'd like you can rip the DVD to an .iso on your desktop. Brasero could probably create one for you.